# Access denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (PHP 5.2.17 + mySQL 5.5.8 + Windows 7)

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

I wanted to test a script written for PHP 5.3.5 (installed as Apache module) in PHP 5.2 environment.

I installed a fresh copy of Apache 2.0.64 and PHP 5.2.17 and configured it EXACTLY as I had configured PHP 5.3 before. Except I did copy `libmysql.dll` into Apache bin directory (PHP 5.3 doesn't have this file anymore).

Both servers are configured by hand (not a XAMPP versions or something) and access the same locally installed mySQL Server 5.5.8. Both servers are running as Windows Server under the system account.

PHP 5.3 works perfectly, PHP 5.2 returns an error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied 
for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Tools\htdocs\myscript.php on line 33
```

The SQL-user I am using is hardcoded in PHP code ant it is not `SYSTEM@localhost`. SYSTEM seems to be a Windows account the Apache is running under. (If I start the Apache from the Administrator account, the message changes to `Administrator@localhost`.)

The default user (with a name '') was deleted on my SQL-Server. If this empty-user exists, the PHP 5.2 connects to the database successfully, but fails on the database selection (`mysql_select_db`) because of permissions.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to connect to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `sql.safe_mode` (NOT the PHP safe mode) in **on** in the `php.ini`, PHP is always using the script owner to connect to the SQL server and not the user specified in `mysql_connect()`.

I mixed up the property `safe_mode` and `sql.safe_mode` during the configuration and it cost me 6 hours!

The answer was found here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.mysql.php#72632

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not specifying the proper username and password for `mysql_connect`.  Instead of leaving them blank (and letting PHP use the default user), specify an actual username and password that was added to MySQL using `GRANT` (or phpMyAdmin, or any other admin client).

Allowing password-less authentication is a huge no-no.  Allowing administrator access without a password is just plain horrific.  Instead, create limited user accounts for all of your programs.  Only use privileged accounts when *absolutely* necessary...