# Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, mysql-error-1045

I have created a database by name 'somedatabase' in mysql

```
CREATE DATABASE somedatabase;  
GRANT ALL ON somedatabase.* TO 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

but when i try to access this database using php application i get the following error

> "**mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access
>   denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**"

The Mysql query browser does allow me to login to this database using username : someuser and password : somepassword. Then why is that i am not able to connect to database through application.

php code :

```
$db_url = 'mysql://someuser:*somepassword*@localhost/somedatabase';
```

Comment: This is only assignment in variable what function are you using to connect to mysql?

Comment: What happens if you try from the command line with the mysql command line program?

Comment: Can you show the full PHP connection code section?

Comment: @dj_segfault : even from command line i am able to login to this database : mysql -u someuser -p..

Comment: Here is a thread with similar situation and a fix : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958564/access-denied-for-user-systemlocalhost-php-5-2-17-mysql-5-5-8-windows-7

Comment: Please show us full code how you use Drupal functions to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use singlequote (') around someuser when using GRANT.

```
GRANT ALL ON somedatabase.* TO someuser@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

I am also assuming that you're running Apache/PHP on the same box as MySQL.

Comment: Are you running Apache on the same box as MySQL? If not then you've to create the grant for the requesting server, or for all('%').

Comment: ya i am running Apache on the same box as Mysql

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. the solution of my problem by was setting the host , for some reason php was not connecting for user at any host (%)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON somedatabase.* TO 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/adding-users.html