# Login form not connecting to Db

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have the following PHP code... (sensitive data switched with +++)

```
<?php

$host="triplestrata.com"; // Host name 
$username="+++"; // Mysql username 
$password="+++"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="+++"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="++_+++"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("triplestrata.com", "+++", "+++")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("+++")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$user_login=$_POST['user_login']; 
$user_pass=$_POST['user_pass']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$user_login= stripslashes($user_login);
$user_pass= stripslashes($user_pass);
$user_login= mysql_real_escape_string($user_login);
$user_pass= mysql_real_escape_string($user_pass);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$user_login' and password='$user_pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $user_login and $user_pass, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $user_login, $user_pass and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("user_login ");
session_register("user_pass"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

I know this sounds like a pretty basic question but where do I input my Db data? I've tried placing it in the beginning but it doesn't work. I get a connection error.

Then there's *how* I should put it, when placing the username and Db name, should I include or ignore the prefix? IE a Db named 'mybase' and the username 'user1':

would it be

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user1"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mybase"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name
```

?

I get this error:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'user'@'cpanel.123.45.67.89.webhost.com' (using password: YES) in /home/user/public_html/checklogin.php on line 11
cannot connect

But I changed everything to match the Db tables... Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: Try not using hyphens for anything in SQL (unless doing math), because it may be interpreted as a math problem. I.e.: `$db_name="my-database-name";` try renaming it to `$db_name="my_database_name";` may or may not be the issue, but it's still good practice. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: **Do.  Not.  Use.  `mysql_query`.**  It is deprecated, and your peers will consider you a horrible person for inflicting it on them.  Learn about PDO and/or mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the DB connection info to variables (e.g. $host, $username, etc). You shouldn't put quotes around those variables when connecting. Instead of passing "localhost" as the host you are passing "$host". Try this:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

If that doesn't work, include the connection error that you are receiving.

I'm not sure if this is related to your error, but it may be helpful. (Make sure the username and password format is correct)

[Mysql cannot connect - Access denied (using password yes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633020/mysql-cannot-connect-access-denied-using-password-yes)

Comment: I'm using the username and password of the selected database but do I have to add the prefix too? I'm using cPanel and they gave me a username of their own and when I created the database there's a prefix there like: USER_databasename

Comment: Disregard, This is what I had wrong, will test it now. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I think you need to use this format if you are using a MySQL username: <cpanel-username>_<mysql-username> Alternatively you should be able to connect using just your cPanel username and password.

Comment: I got the DB connected now. Thanks everyone for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes on the variables on these lines:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

To make these:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**

**Use prepared statements and parameterized queries**. These are SQL statements that are sent to and parsed by the database server separately from any parameters. This way it is impossible for an attacker to inject malicious SQL.

Mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should use **[PDO](http://php.net/pdo)** or **[mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** instead

Comment: OK, I'll try both right away! Thanks. But could you give me an example of a parameterized query? Thanks

Comment: Good. Post any other error(s) you may encounter as you go along @WindSplitter1

Comment: I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_MUL_EQUAL in /home/user/public_html/checklogin.php on line 10. This is what I got in line 10: **mysql_connect(triplestrata.com, user, password)or die("cannot connect"); **

Comment: You're making one mistake. You already assigned these values to a variable. Use the variables without "" or use strings with "" i.e. you can either do `mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)` or `mysql_connect("localhost", "yourusername", "yourpassword");`

Comment: REMEMBER: `mysql_*` functions **have been deprecated**

Comment: And @WindSplitter1 the username and database name prefixes you see in cPanel **are part of the username and database name**