# How do I resolve a "warning" that says that it could not connect to the sql server using password:YES?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'msuparam_17'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/msuparam/public_html/17database/Formfeed/Formreg.php on line 11
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'msuparam_17'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: You have the wrong password, or the IP address you're connecting from doesn't have permission to connect to MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql cannot connect - Access denied (using password yes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633020/mysql-cannot-connect-access-denied-using-password-yes)

Answer (score 0):

`Access denied for user 'msuparam_17'@'localhost'`

Access denied means that you were able to establish a connection to the server, but it has rejected your credentials.

Either you have typed the wrong username, the wrong password, or this user does not actually have privileges to login.

If you can login to the database as an authorized user, verify this user actually exists, and is permitted to login.

```
mysql -u root -p
Password:
mysql> use mysql;

# Verify user actually exists
mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM user WHERE User="msuparam_17";

# Check permission for user
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'msuparam_17'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Matt Thanks... Your answer helped to resolve the error.